# tsx and jsx files for require.context

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack

I want to be able to search for both `.jsx` and `.tsx` files using [webpack's require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context). How can I do this? I am assuming I need to adjust my regex somehow? This is how I am currently looking for my `.jsx` files:

`const req = require.context('../src/app/app', true, /\.stories\.jsx$/);`

Comment: What is this parameter `/\.stories\.jsx$/` and what does it do ?

Comment: Did you try `/\.stories\.[tj]sx$/` ?

Comment: that works @sin, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily adjust your regex to match both `.jsx` and `.tsx`

```
[tj]sx$
```

- `[tj]` - Match `t` or `j`
- `sx` - Match `sx`
- `$` - End of string

---

```
 const req = require.context('../src/app/app', true, /\.stories\.[tj]sx$/);
```